# Constant property/column value for objects in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i have a class

```
class User:
    constant_value = 5
```

when i use "mapper" the property goes away.  how do i preserve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use exclude_properties:

```
mapper(Address, addresses_table,
            exclude_properties=['street', 'city', 'state', 'zip'])
```